# Copying a region of pixels from an image

Tags: c

Get a new image which is a copy of the region. Empty regions return
a null pointer. If memory allocation fails, return a null
pointer. The caller is responsible for freeing the returned array.

The region includes all the columns from `[left, right-1]` inclusive,
and all the rows from `[top, bottom-1]` inclusive.

In every case, you may assume that `left <= right` and `top <= bottom`:
do not need to test for this.

The area of the region is `(right-left) * (bottom-top)` pixels, which
implies that if `left == right` or `top == bottom`, the region has no
area and is defined as "empty". Each function notes how to handle
empty regions.

This solution elicits an error in the terminal called "memory corruption" and it points at my malloc function call followed by a very strange number along the lines of `0x00001dec880`, it differs each time it compiles. I am not sure why this is and help would be appreciated

```
uint8_t* region_copy( const uint8_t array[], unsigned int cols, unsigned int rows, 
                      unsigned int left, unsigned int top, unsigned int right, unsigned int bottom ) {

    unsigned int corner1 = left + (top*cols);
    unsigned int corner2 = right + (bottom*cols);
    unsigned int newsize = (right - left) * (bottom - top);

    if(left==right || top == bottom ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    uint8_t* newimg = malloc(newsize * sizeof(uint8_t));

    if(newimg == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(newimg, 0, newsize);

    for(int i = corner1; i < corner2; i++) {
        newimg[i] = array[i];
    }

    return newimg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop is wrong:

```
for(int i = corner1; i < corner2; i++) {
    newimg[i] = array[i]; }
```

The indices for the source and destination need to be different, since their dimensions are different. You can do soemthing like this:

```
for (int r = top; r < bottom; r++)             // for each source row
{
    for (int c = left; c < right; c++)         // for each source col
    {
        int src_index = r * cols + c;          // calc source index in array[]
        int dst_index = (r - top) * (right - left) + (c - left);
                                               // calc dest index in newimg[]
        newimg[dst_index] = array[src_index];  // copy src -> dest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for(int i = corner1; i < corner2; i++) {
    newimg[i] = array[i]; }
```

copies *from* `array[i]`, which is what you want, but it also copies *to* `newimg` in the same position; as if `newimg` is exactly as large as `array`. You need to copy to `newimg` starting at its 0th index:

```
for(int i = corner1; i < corner2; i++) {
    newimg[i-corner1] = array[i]; }
```

or the more clear operation

```
for(int i = 0; i< corner2 - corner1; i++) {
    newimg[i] = array[corner1 + i]; }
```

It's "more clear" because then it's obvious you copy `corner2 - corner1` elements, starting at `corner1`.

But it's not the only thing wrong! I will only outline it here, as it will take a serious re-write.

You copy the "rows * columns" *contiguously*, that is, starting at the top left corner and continuing to the bottom right corner:

```
..........
..********
**********
******....
..........
```

but you must copy each column (or row) independently:

```
..........
..****....
..****....
..****....
..........
```